# Loading a png file created from a php script

Tags: java, url, bitmap, httpresponse

I am downloading png files to a bimap.

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream());
```

It works perfectly for "static"· images,images stored in a server with his .png file extension

But if the image is a jsp script response nothing is downloaded into the bitmap

The url of the script

```
http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:9000/xxxxxxx/jsp/ios/imageAlumno?X_ALUMNO=144244
```

The image is displayed properly in a browser and the html code of the response is:

`<html><body style="margin: 0px;"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:9000/XXXXXXX/jsp/ios/imageAlumno?X_ALUMNO=144244"></body></html`>

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure the JSP returns a PNG image?  It might be returning a different kind of image, like a GIF or JPEG.

Comment: sure it's a png file. bitmap value is null after BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream())

Answer (score 0):

First guess is: the JSP code sends wrong image header. Java is probably less permissive than a web browser when it comes to certain rules... I would first check what header is sent back to the user. Use the `telnet XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:9000`, and then type in the `GET /XXXXXXX/jsp/ios/imageAlumno?X_ALUMNO=144244` to pretend you are a browser, and you will see what the web server sends back.

Comment: The JSP *should* return the proper `Content-type` header, but I don't think it matters in this case.  He's just passing an `InputStream` object into the `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` method.  There's no way you can read the HTTP headers from that InputStream because the InputStream only contains the body of the response.

Comment: That's what i thougth...I only read the body.Anyway, I get a "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/png." message warning at chrome console but it's the same message I got from other images that are loaded correctly.

Comment: @pekechis Stream the input stream data to a file and then try to see if you can open it as an image.

Comment: @Michael: "_The image is displayed properly in a browser_"

Comment: @DejanLekic *Maybe there is something wrong with the way that Java is making the HTTP request*

Comment: solved...it's a problem of the http client. I wasn't storing cookies and i needed session cookie to retrieve the file...big fail for me...hope this helps somebody